# How do I solve for x with a known function in equation using numpy/scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a lognorm distribution from scipy and its parameters are known.

```
import scipy

log_norm_obj = scipy.stats.lognorm([log_mu], shape=sigma)
```

I need to solve for a x which satisfies the following equation:

```
x = (1 - log_norm_obj.cdf(x)) / log_norm_obj.pdf(x)
```

How could I do this using numpy/scipy? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html). From scipy 0.11 and later, you can use the new functions [`minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) or [`minimize_scalar`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar). Assuming your x is a scalar, here's some example code on how to do it:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

def f(x):
    return (1 - log_norm_obj.cdf(x)) / log_norm_obj.pdf(x) - x

result = minimize_scalar(f)        
print result.x 
# this would print your result
```

The above uses [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method), the default. You can also the [Golden method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search), or a bounded version of Brent's method. The latter could be useful if your function is only defined in a given domain or you want a solution in a specific interval. An example of this:

```
result = minimize_scalar(f, bounds=(0, 10.), method='bounded')
```

If your function takes a vector instead of a scalar, a similar approach can be taken using `minimize`. If your scipy is older than version 0.11, just use a flavour of [`fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin).